# Parse schema of a dynamic dataframe in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a dynamic dataframe in AWS glue which I created using the below piece of code.

```
val rawDynamicDataFrame = glueContext.getCatalogSource(
    database = rawDBName, 
    tableName = rawTableName, 
    redshiftTmpDir = "", 
    transformationContext = "rawDynamicDataFrame"
).getDynamicFrame()
```

In order to get the schema of the above dynamic frame, I used the below piece of code:

```
val x = rawDynamicDataFrame.schema
```

Now `x` is of type `com.amazonaws.services.glue.schema.Schema`. How can I parse the schema object?

Comment: The object is parsed representation of the schema and contains all fields and their types as properties of the object. What do you mean when you say 'parse' the schema?

Comment: Yes that's true.I need to check if a column is present in the schema object or not.Suppose my schema object is like below.`com.amazonaws.services.glue.schema.Schema = {"dataType":"struct","fields":[{"name":"app_name","container":{"dataType":"string","properties":{}},"properties":{}},{"name":"country","container":{"dataType":"string","properties":{}}}`.Now I need to check if `app_name` is present in schema or not

Answer (score 0):

To check if a field exist in schema use `containsField(fieldPath)`:

```
if (rawDynamicDataFrame.schema.containsField("app_name")) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: hey @Yuriy, It is throwing error in Glue 3.0 with PySpark like 'function' object has no attribute 'containsField'. Also, I am unable to find containsField method in documentation. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `field_names = [field.name for field in self. rawDynamicDataFrame.schema().fields]` to get a list of field names.